# Namespace in module VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

I would like to know if there is any way to make a namespace (or something like that) into a module, is just for code sorting, something like this:

```
Public Module1

    Namespace N1 (or whatever)

        Public N1_1 as integer = 45    

    End Namespace

    Namespace N2 (or whatever)

        Public N2_1 as integer = 28

    End Namespace


End Module
```

So then I can do:

```
Module1.N1.N1_1
```

Thanks!

Edit: values must be able to be changed so I can't use Enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap multiple classes into a namespace instead.

Your classes would then only have Shared members / properties.

Something like this:

```
Namespace Module1
    Class N1 (or whatever)
        Public Shared N1_1 as integer = 45    
    End Class

    Class N2 (or whatever)
        Public Shared N2_1 as integer = 28
    End Class
End Namespace
```